# Android layout style differences

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to understand the difference between the above 2 styles. It appears after reading various posts the correct way of doing this is assigning the holo theme in the manifest and then doing

```
   style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

but it appears you can also do this

```
   style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small"
```

which one is correct? Is one an alias for the other?

I must admit the second 1 seems easier to read and understand, its pointing to an internal style - right?

and the 1st one? this is a style or just an attribute within a style?

In the 1st one it also starts with a question mark, what purpose does this have ?

anybody have a good insight into this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which one is correct?

Both/either, depending upon your objective.

> Is one an alias for the other?

The first one says "there's an [attribute in the theme](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#borderlessButtonStyle) that will indicate what style to use here". The second one says "use this style".

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying in fact that  style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" points to    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small" ?

Comment: AH ok.  So applying an attribute only takes part of the style...If you apply a style then you might take other parts of the style that isn't needed. Still a little confused here.

Comment: @Martin: "So are you saying in fact that style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" points to style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless.Small" ?" -- I have no idea, as I haven't looked.